# Find Hidden Account in Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory, user-accounts, administrator

I am a admin of a large AD domain, and I have been told there is an enterprise admin account in Active Directory, but when I look in the Enterprise Admins group, I don't see any accounts; this leaves me to believe it is hidden somehow.

I have tried using ADUC advanced features, but still can't see this mystery account.

I have tried using PowerShell, but I don't know of any code to find this account.

Can someone please help?

Comment: I’d like to help, but the question doesn’t make much sense. You can check in ADSI to see if the object is only visible in Advanced Features mode, but that should be the only variable. Can whoever told you about this account give you more detail?

Comment: This is an infrastructure administration question, not a programming question, hence it belongs on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: There is no built-in "Enterprise Admin" account in AD. So if your organization has one, then it's something that someone in your organization created, and no one outside of your organization can help you find it. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/security-best-practices/appendix-b--privileged-accounts-and-groups-in-active-directory#enterprise-admins)